# Pandas Dataframe delete Row if string matches

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
def clean_doc (df): 
 for rownum in range(0,df.shape[0]):
    if "LM_" not in df.iloc[rownum][6]:
        clean_df = df.drop([df.index[rownum]])
 return clean_df
```

I want to delete a row if it does not start with "LM_"

Also tried:

```
df.drop([rownum])
```

and many more, but it only deletes one line of my dataset.. but it should be a lot more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
df[df['<your_column>'].str.startswith('LM_')]
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['abc', 'LM_abc']})

print(df[df['col'].str.startswith('LM_')])
```

Output:

```
      col
1  LM_abc
```

Your code is only deleting one line because you're overwriting the `clean_df` variable every time you loop.

Comment: I think OP wants `df[~df['<your_column>'].str.startswith('LM_')]` instead.

Comment: @HenryYik I think it's the opposite, OPs code is deleting rows that do not contain `LM_`